# Nothing happens when creating a Greeter object - getting started with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm absolutely new to Ruby and I'm using my Mac terminal.
I'm following [this getting-started tutorial](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/3/) but after I created a Greeter object:

```
g = Greeter.new("Pat")
```

Nothing happens, no error messages whatsoever.
I though I'm supposed to see something like:

```
=> #<Greeter:0x16cac @name="Pat">
```

What's wrong, am I supposed to install something extra for Ruby to work properly on my Mac?

Comment: Are you using only your Mac terminal or have you started IRB in it? If you haven't started IRB, I suggest you read the first page of the tutorial first: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

Comment: Try restarting irb, there might have been some wrong input and it's still expecting a closing bracket for example. so it's not executing your input yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: :)

```
class Greeter
 def initialize(x)
  @name = x
 end
end
p g = Greeter.new("Pat") #=> #<Greeter:0x105c840 @name="Pat">
```

Or if you started this way:

```
C:\>irb --simple-prompt --noecho
>> class Greeter
>>  def initialize(x)
>>   @name = x
>>  end
>> end
>> g = Greeter.new("Pat")
>> p g
#<Greeter:0x11e8300 @name="Pat">
```

Nothing would come as `--noecho` option disable the `IRB` inspection as `=>`.